# JQuery JSONP polling memory leaks

Tags: jquery, memory-leaks, jsonp

I need to perform jsonp long polling in highly dynamic web application, however I'm experiencing massive memory leaks. Initially I've used Socket.IO and the jsonp transport with the same results and then setup a JQuery test page to see if the problem was localized only in the socket.io lib.
I've found to my surprise that also doing jsonp polling from JQuery lead to the same results: in IE9 the memory increases very fast(less than 10 min ) from around 80-90 MB to more than 1.8 GB :(.

He're is the test code for the client side:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">        
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready( function() {
            var doPoll = function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: "http://<server-url>/jquery-jsonp/server.php",
                    cache: false,
                    async: true,
                    crossDomain: true,
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    success: function (data, status) {
                        console.log("Received response"+data);
                        doPoll();
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        // access denied
                    }
                });
            }

            doPoll();     
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

And here is the dummy server response:

```
<?php echo $_GET['callback']."(".json_encode(array("status"=>"success")).")";
```

As you can see nothing special here. Any thoughts on what is causing this and possible work-arounds ?

The request need to be performed cross origin and we must support IE8/9.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you get any solution for this problem? It occurs for me as well... Problem here is, that we are using Phonegap for a mobile application and there the Problem occurs even when I change the pages... :-X

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `doPoll()` at an interval of a few seconds, like this:

```
success: function (data, status) {
    console.log("Received response"+data);
    setTimeout(doPoll, 10000); // 10 second wait before next request sent
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to poll the moment you've received a response. HTTP transmissions may be slow in comparison to regular computer operations but they're still typically a bit faster than a human reaction. A delay of at least a few seconds would be a good idea.

That said it should be noted that HTTP polling is pretty unreliable at best. Take the HTML facebook chat as an indicator of just how unreliable it can be.

**EDIT:**

> Guys, thanks for the responses. Delaying the next request is not an
>   option for this app

Then you shouldn't be using a web page for this. Write a desktop or a mobile app instead. If your response is "That's not an option either." then no viable options exist. HTTP/HTML/Javascript is simply *not* intended for "highly dynamic, critical business updates delivered to the user every second" and I doubt it ever will be.

Comment: Guys, thanks for the responses. Delaying the next request is not an option for this app, unfortunately, as it's highly dynamic, and it's critical bussines wise that all the updates are delivered to the UI every second, as soon as possible( every second a lot of different things can happen server side and the UI needs to be notified of all of them ). So I need to do at least 5 -10 requests per seconds and that's why I wanted initially to use Socket.IO but the memory problems are still there even in this lib.

Comment: I've also tried with regular XHR polling instead of JSONP to see what happens( just removed the dataType: "jsonp" setting and replaced it with dataType:"json". The rest of the code is unchanged) and the memory goes up but at a far slower rate than using jsonp( in ~1h it grew from 40MB to 300MB ). I'll check to see if it stops at some point and update the comment. Nonetheless I still don't get it why the JSONP eats up so much memory and why even the XHR polling technique continues to grow up the memory usage on IE9. I would expect that the memory gets cleaned up from time to time.

Comment: You can try to use WebSockets, which keep a connection open to the server, and the server can push data to the user when it needs to, instead of the user constantly pinging for updates. But come on, you can't even delay 250 milliseconds?? What kind of business (non-game) app cannot even wait 250 ms

Answer (score 0):

All the suggestions are valid and even if you need to poll the server every half second, you should add a couple of miliseconds timeout to give javascript a small pause, so it can start clearing the memory.

Another problem is with JSONP, as this will create new  tags with the response in the DOM. You should start deleting the unused nodes, otherwise the size of your page will grow indefinitely and eventually go out of memory.